Testnet deploying contracts
I'm new to developing, and I have a question about fees. For example, the maximum ETH to gain from the faucet is 0.1 ETH, and to deploy my contract on test net cost me 0.8, nearly all my ETH. How do you guys try your contracts, how do you deploy them on testnet, or do you gain somewhere else more eth than 0.1? Thanks for responding! Plz be aware that I'm new in all of this so if this sounds like something stupid don't get angry at me. Thanks !

You need to "mine" test coins from a testnet faucet . You need atleast 2 gitcoin passport points to be able to mine sepolia testnet coins, because there are a lot of bots mining and the faucet wants to verify you are a human. You can get passport points by linking your socials, github etc to your wallet here -gitcoin passport 
You can also prove that there are transactions you have undertaken on ethereum mainnet from the same wallet to get passport points .
Sepolia faucet -
https://sepolia-faucet.pk910.de/

If you find this info helpful, mark this as the correct answer @Pecrej

Another option is Alchemy or Infura.
https://www.infura.io/faucet/sepolia
https://www.alchemy.com/faucets/ethereum-sepolia
I would like to see your Smart Contract or your Project, because until now I haven't seen such high fees.
